# Splitting SSIS Variable by Delimeter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an `SSIS package (2008)` which emails files from a given folder. I'm passing the file name from the `Foreach container` to a send email task. I would then like to split the variable containing the file name into sections (using delimeter "-") for use in the email subject line. For example:

`The file name is 123456-London-Jobrequirements.doc`

The email subject would read:

`**Jobrequirements** document received for account **123456**, **London** Area.`

I've tried to split using the expression builder with `SUBSTRING` and `FINDSTRING` but cannot get it to identify the `delimiter`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I hope I can safely assume that your file name is pretty much going to be be of this format:

```
<<String1>>-<<String2>>-<<String1>>.doc
```

As you said you are using a ForEachLoop container to iterate through the file names, so I assuming you are having a variable which temporarily stores the file name. Lets call it `@filename`

Below is how you can get the strings:

```
@String1 = SUBSTRING(@filename, 1, FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",1)-1)
@String2 = SUBSTRING(@filename, FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",1)+1, FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",1)-1)
@String3 = SUBSTRING(@filename, FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",2)+1, FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",1)-1)
```

You can then combine these into another variable say `@finalstring`

Then using expression you can form the string as:

```
@String3 + " document received for account " + @String1 + " , " + @String2 + " Area."
```

A point worth mentioning is that Microsoft had introduced an extremely useful keyword called `TOKEN` in SSIS 2012 . Needless to say it would have made the expression MUCH cleaner looking.

```
@String1 = TOKEN(@filename, "-", 1)
@String2 = TOKEN(@filename, "-", 2)
@String3 = TOKEN(@filename, "-", 3)
```

[MSDN link on TOKEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213216.aspx)

**Adding variables:**

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for this. Where do I need to enter the code assiging string1, string 2 etc. Is this in the Foreach part of the package?

Comment: First you would need to declare the variables in the `Variables pane`. Then using `Expression Builder` dialogue box, you would need to provide the expressions. Added screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. I just built the expression after declaring the string variable. However, I get the error "The length -1 is not valid for function SUBSTRING. The Length parameter cannot be negative"

Comment: Evaluate what this returns: `FINDSTRING(@filename, "-",1)`

Comment: That's strange. Is your `@filename` variable even capturing the file name? What is `@filename` evaluating to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84790/discussion-between-sourava-and-aphrek).

Comment: think I have sorted - just needed a default value for @filename. Thanks!